# running parallel bash background

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have a script that I want to run on a number of files

```
my_script file_name
```

but I have many so I have written some code that is meant to process multiple at the same time by first creating 5 'equal' lists of the files I want to process followed by this

```
my_function() {
    while read i; do 
        my_script $i
    done < $1
}

my_function list_1 &
my_function list_2 &
my_function list_3 &
my_function list_4 &
my_function list_5 &

wait
```

This works for the first file in each list but then finishes. If I change the function to a simple echo it works fine

```
my_function() {
    while read i; do 
        echo $i
    done < $1 
}
```

it prints all the files in each list as I would expect.

Why does it not work if I use 'my_script'?? And is there a 'nicer' way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a typo in your code, shouldn't `done < $i` be `done < $1` instead?

Comment: Yep sorry typo corrected

Answer (score 2):

GNU Parallel is made for this:

```
parallel my_script ::: files*
```

You can find more about GNU Parallel at: http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/ 
You can install GNU Parallel in just 10 seconds with:

```
wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh
```

Watch the intro video on http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Edit:

If the reason for not installing GNU Parallel is not covered by
http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html
would you then be kind to elaborate why?

Comment: I cant use GNU Parallel for this unfortunately. Which is why I am doing it this way.

Comment: Its kind of related to the reason "I do not have root access" (I don't even fully understand why I cant) but I am hoping to change this but for the moment I would just like to solve this without gnu parallel

Answer (score 0):

There must be an exit statement in my_script. Replace the exit statement(s) with return statement(s).

Another thing to check is the possibility that the same file is contained in more than one list. There may be contention issues in processing - the file is already being processed and another process attempts to open the same file. Check for any duplicate files with-:

```
sort file_[1-5] | uniq -d
```

Comment: I have changed the exit statements in my_script to return 1 but it still does the same thing and ends before moving onto the next file

Comment: try `set -vx; my_script list_1; set +vx` - is some error indicated?

Comment: Did you mean `set -vx; my_script file; set +vx` - I dont get any errors.

Comment: sorry - `set -vx; for p in $(cat list_1);do; my_script $p; done; set +vx` - which should loop through all the list_1 parameters. What the check should do is indicate if there are any issues with my_script given the parameters in list_1 file.

Comment: This successfully performed my_script on all the files in list_1 as I would like

Comment: Interesting. I've added to the answer just in case a duplicate file could be causing an issue. The other thing I would check is repeat the above `$(cat list_N)` etc checks with each of the lists (list_2 to list_5).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to GNU parallel, there is https://github.com/mauvilsa/run_parallel which is simply a function in bash, so it does not require root access or compiling.

To use it, first source the file

```
source run_parallel.inc.sh
```

Then in your example, execute it as

```
run_parallel -T 5 my_function 'list_{%}'
```

It could also do the splitting of the lists for you as

```
run_parallel -T 5 -l full_list -n split my_function '{@}'
```

To see the usage explanation and some examples, execute run_parallel without any arguments.